# Magento 2 : Top rated products on homepage

Tags: magento2

How to get top rated products in homepage magento 2?

we have to display top rated products list in homepage  in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getRatingSummary()
{

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $reviewFactory = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory::class);
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();
    $rating = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
        if($ratingSummary!=null){
            $rating[$product->getId()] = $ratingSummary;
        }
    }
    return $rating;
}
```

Use this code in your custom block to get ids of rated products and call one template file with this block to display product data

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this extension [this link contains the download path](https://github.com/OxCom/magento2-top-products)
features -
TOP selling products
TOP Free products
TOP Rated products